# Working with large amount of data with multiple duplicates in ruby

Tags: ruby, set, bigdata

I have a large text file which I want to process with a ruby script and store in a separate file. My problem is that the resulting file will consist of hundreds of million of lines where the vast majority of them are duplicates. I would like to eliminate the duplicates before writing them to disk.

I have tried processing them and putting the lines in a set to eliminate the duplicates before writing them to the output file, but eventually I ran out of memory and the script crashed.

Is there a way to solve my problem efficiently in ruby?

Comment: How does the data on your textfile looks like? Also, how fast the script needs to be?

Comment: It is readable text in the English language of varying length. Each line can be from 5 to 500 characters. Preferably it should be as fast as possible :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file called `uniq.rb` with this code:

```
require 'digest'

hashes = {}

STDIN.each do |line|
  line.chomp!
  md5 = Digest::MD5.digest(line)
  next if hashes.include?(md5)
  hashes[md5] = true
  puts line
end
```

then run it from the command line:

```
ruby uniq.rb < input.txt > output.txt
```

The main idea is that you don't have to save the entire line in memory, but instead just a 16-byte MD5 hash (plus `true` value) to track the unique lines.

Comment: Nice solution! I was thinking about something similar - create a MD5 or SHA1 hash for each line, storing it in a hash table, etc. I think indexes works in that way.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out as soon as I get the chance. So basically I can do it like this as well: ruby process.rb | ruby uniq.rb > output.txt

Comment: @user3207230 Under reasonable assumptions yes

Comment: It worked great. However memory will get full soon enough, even with this solution. Is there a way store the hashes on disk so I dont have to recalculate them every time I run the program?

Comment: @user3207230 Though I haven't used this myself, I might try [`PStore`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html).

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll check it out. Thanks

Comment: Ended up using GDBM and so far I have no complaints.

Comment: @user3207230 OK thanks for the info. GDBM seems simpler and more direct than PStore.

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter you can use Unix `uniq` command.

```
ruby process.rb | sort | uniq > out.txt
```